# recursive function affecting variable

Tags: python, recursion, counter

I have a recursive function to count the number of way 8 queens can fit on an 8x8 chess board without intersecting each other (for a class). It works well and gives the correct permutations, the interesting thing happens when I have the program try to count the # of answers -it constantly returns my counter to zero. When I manually count the permutations it's 92 (which is correct).

```
def can_be_extended_to_solution(perm):
    i = len(perm) - 1
    for j in range(i):
        if i - j == abs(perm[i] - perm[j]):
            return False
    return True

def extend(perm,count, n):
    if len(perm)==n:
        count=count+1
        print "cycle counter= ",count
        print(perm)

    for k in range(n):
        if k not in perm:
            perm.append(k)
            if can_be_extended_to_solution(perm): # if it works
                extend(perm, count, n)
            perm.pop()        

extend(perm = [], count=0, n = 8)
```

Comment: Right, a permutation of length 8 is considered an answer. So every time it finds a solution with 8 queens it should increment count. Count at the end should be the number of permutations of 8 queens possible, but for some reason count gets returned to 0 after every iteration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you never allow the recursive call to modify the value of `count`. You pass the `count` value in to the function, but then when the `count = count + 1` line is called, it only modifies the *local* value of `count` for that function call, and does not modify the value in the call that recursively called it.

The following modification works just fine (the return value of `extend` is 92).

```
def can_be_extended_to_solution(perm):
    i = len(perm) - 1
    for j in range(i):
        if i - j == abs(perm[i] - perm[j]):
            return False
    return True


def extend(perm, count, n):
    if len(perm) == n:
        count = count + 1
        print("cycle counter= " + str(count))
        print(perm)

    for k in range(n):
        if k not in perm:
            perm.append(k)
            if can_be_extended_to_solution(perm): # if it works
                count = extend(perm, count, n)
            perm.pop()
    return count

print(extend(perm=[], count=0, n=8))
```

Comment: Thank you! That was really bugging me, so there was nothing passing the count variable back to the function that called the recursive function. I got lucky with perm because it only finds permutations in the forward (passing arguments into a function) direction.